# In jQuery UI sortable, how do I get the element undernearth a dragged element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Let's say you have 5 elements, labeled item 1,..,5.

Here is sample code illustrating this:

```
   <ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

If I drag item 1 over item 2, **what event can I hook into to get the element under item 1 (which is item 2 in this case, but could be item 3 or 4 or 5.)**

Note: Mouseover event gives me the item I am dragging (in this case item 1) and not the item under it (in this case, item 2.) So, that is not an option AFAIK.

I have included a jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/H6f2S/2/

Comment: Maybe you could get it from a mouseover event?

Comment: @kehrk: Good observation but unfortunately mouseover does not help (and was my first thought). Mouseover event give me the item I am moving, not the one under it (in my illustration, item 1)

Comment: I've never worked with jQuery draggable before so that's probably the best I'll be able to contribute. Good luck.

Comment: @kehrk: Thanks. Plus, you did help me update the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the jQuery UI draggable API provide such a method.

I wrote a quick'n'dirty solution:

```
$("#sortable .ui-sortable-helper").live('mousemove', function(e) {
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;

    var hoveredElement;
    // Iterate through all draggable elements (not the current one, not the helper)
    $("#sortable > li:not(.ui-sortable-helper, .ui-sortable-placeholder)").each(function(_, li) {
        var $li = $(li);
        var liOffset = $li.offset();
        var height = $li.outerHeight();
        var width = $li.outerWidth();
        // Test if mouse is in block bounds
        if (y >= liOffset.top &&  y <= liOffset.top + height
            && x >= liOffset.left && x <= liOffset.left + width) {
            hoveredElement = $li;
            return false;
        }
    });
    console.log(hoveredElement);
});
```

<kbd>[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H6f2S/3/)</kbd>

Please note few things:

- You can cache jQuery selector in order to improve performance
- Since your fiddle use jQuery 1.6.4 (!), I have used `.live()`, which is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. You should use `.on()` instead.
- This code does not take currently dragged element size. Thus, only the mouse position is checked, not the whole `<li>` element bounds.

Comment: Brilliant. I will experiment with this and resolve this question if your suggestion works. I thought about a similar approach but approached it wrong.  I was looking for an jQuery API or DOM API that gives me all documents in range of pageX and pageY. It failed to dawn on me that it may not exist and there is probably no reason why it should.

Comment: There is one, `elementFromPoint(x, y)`, but it will only returns the top-most element (i.e. the element *visible* at a given `(x,y)`).